# Regarding circle rotations and composites

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, circles, ergodic-theory

Let $S^1$ be the unit circle in the additive notation $[0,1)~mod~ 1$ and $0< \alpha<1$ be an irrational number. Let $\tau$ be the irrational rotation defined by $\alpha$ given by $\tau(x)=x+\alpha ~mod ~1$. For $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, I have seen that $\tau^n(x)=x+n\alpha ~mod ~1$ that is rotation by $n\alpha$. But for large $n$, $x+n\alpha$ can be very large right? What will be the inverse of $\tau$? is $\tau^{-1}(x)=x-\alpha ~mod ~(-1)$? I couldn't understand the rotation map in the additive notation of $S^1$. I wanted to prove that if $\beta \in$ Orbit($\alpha)$, then $0 \leq x <\tau^{-n}(\beta)<x'<\beta$ implies that $0<\tau^n(x)<\beta<\tau^n(x)\leq 1$

Comment: $\mathrm{mod}\, 1$ is just a fancy way of saying "take the fractional part".

Comment: Can we write a closed form expression for inverse map same as $\tau$?

Comment: Yes. Try it! Here $\tau$ happens to have an inverse.

Comment: inverse will be rotation by $-\alpha$. So we have to take the fractional part of $x-\alpha$. So $\tau^-1(x)=x-\alpha~~mod~~(-1)$?  Then $\tau^{-n}$ will be rotation by $-n\alpha$.My doubt is what happens if $x-n\alpha$ falls below $-2$ for large $n$? $x-n\alpha+1$ will also be strictly less than $-1$. How to write a closed form expression for $\tau^{-n}$?

Comment: Don't write $\mod 1$, write "take the fractional part." Hopefully this will make it clear.

Comment: My main doubt is in the proof of last inequality. I will post it as a separate question

Comment: $\tau^{-1}(x) = x-\alpha \pmod 1$.